# Multiple select box with the same class name how to get the value of select field in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $('.choose').each(function(){ 
   getval.push($(this).val()); 
   for(i=0;i<=getval.length;i++){
      console.log(getval[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Select elements typically have two values that you want to access. First there's the value to be sent to the server, which is easy:

```
$( "#myselect" ).val();
// => 1
```

The second is the text value of the select. For example, using the following select box:

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="1">Mr</option>
<option value="2">Mrs</option>
<option value="3">Ms</option>
<option value="4">Dr</option>
<option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

If you wanted to get the string "Mr" if the first option was selected (instead of just "1") you would do that in the following way:

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
// => "Mr"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
$('.choose').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val(); // You can use the variable value wherever you want
});

$(this).val() will give you the value of the select box which are changing even if there
```

are 1000s pf select boxes with same class.